# React Native : Download and open pdf file, need to work on IOS and Android

Tags: react-native

Using react native I am trying to download a PDF file ([Sample PDF File](http://pepa.holla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Learning-React-Native.pdf)).  After download completes, it should open with 3rd party pdf viewer

Please  guide me how to do this in react native.

Answer (score 4):

1) Download base64 encoded pdf file.

2) Decode base64 encoded file ( I suggest you use react-native filehandler)

3)In order to view pdf you can use webview on IOS

```
     <WebView style={{
          flex: 1
        }}  scalesPageToFit={true} source={{
          uri: --base64EncodedContent--
        }}
        >
       </WebView>
```

for android you can use react-native pdf view https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-pdf-view

```
     <PDFView 
        path={this.props.src} //path of pdf file you saved
        pageNumber={1}
        onLoadComplete = {(pageCount) => {

        }}
        style={styles.pdf}>
        </PDFView>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how to download PDF file? Thank you.

Comment: check this module https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs. It has a method called downloadFile after downloading file you can read it by using readDir function which belongs to the same module(react-native fs)

Comment: I have a pdf file. How can i dowload this file using react-native?