# How can one display a downloaded file in a WebView?

Tags: ios, react-native

I receive the path to a file that has been downloaded to the device. I try using `<WebView source={{ uri }} />` to display the content: i.e. `uri = '/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1897591-5645-4C4F-A3CE-3DE4F7DD67C7/data/Containers/Data/Application/23485972-4B66-4DCF-8101-F419DF12CB87/Documents/RNFetchBlob_tmp/RNFetchBlobTmp_hhbjcw8zag7jqgra3mldkd'`.

All I get is:

`Error loading page
Domain: WebKitErrorDomain
Error Code: 102
Description: Frame load interrupted`

Does WebView actually accepts files stored locally?

Answer (score 1):

WebView for iOS can only open files by path that are stored in you project, not in your app’s file system unfortunately.

You can use webview to open base64encoded content of the file but passing it in the WebView `url={base64encodedcontent}`. Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895475/4655003

You can also try something like this: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/iOS-API#iospreviewdocumentpathstring to use the native UIDocumentController to preview files.

```
RNFetchBlob.ios.previewDocument(pathToLocalFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the solution but it can help you:

**Error Code: 102** occurs when `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` is returning NO (false).